# Query Amazon DynamoDB for specific result

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the DynamoDB SDK v2 . I can scan the database however I am struggling to query it for a specific results. I don't know if I have the DB setup wrong or I am doing the query wrong.

When I use

```
- (void)getTableRow:(NSString *)rangeKey {
          AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
            [[dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[SonicUserTableRow class]
                                hashKey:@"UserId"
                               rangeKey:rangeKey] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                if (!task.error) {

                   SonicUserTableRow *tableRow = task.result;

                   NSLog (@"Table Row %@", tableRow);

            } else {
               //Catch Error

            }
            return nil;
        }];
}
```

I am calling it using `[self getTableRow:@" ENTER UNIQUE USER ID "];`

However I am getting the error

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

How can I fix this?

Note I am using the new Amazon SDK v2.

**My Database**
[image]

**HASH & RANGE KEYS**

[image]

**SonicUserTableRow .m**

```
+ (NSString *)dynamoDBTableName {
    return @"SonicUsers";
}

+ (NSString *)hashKeyAttribute {
    return @"UserId";
}

+ (NSString *)rangeKeyAttribute {
    return @"Username";
}
```

**SonicUserTableRow .h**

```
@interface SonicUserTableRow : AWSDynamoDBModel <AWSDynamoDBModeling>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *UserId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *profileImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *active;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *flags;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *attuned;
```

I have UserId value `UserIdString:  us-east-1:4ae0a93a-59a6-45fd-80c8-ff6b99f1d152` in the database so am trying to call for example: `[self getTableRow:@"us-east-1:4ae0a93a-59a6-45fd-80c8-ff6b99f1d152"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DropId` is a hash key of your table, you can use `- load:hashKey:rangeKey:` to load a single item.

Comment: We have a DynamoDB Object Mapper sample in our [samples GitHub repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples).

Comment: Strugling to get this working even with the github. Updated the question with what I have done and a bounty award

Comment: You should share the definition of `SonicUserTableRow` (both .h and .m files). It may not be set up correctly.

Comment: You should go to the **Details** view in the AWS Management Console and make sure you are seeing `Primary Hash Key: hashKeyAttribute (String)` and `Primary Range Key: rangeKey (String)`. These need to correspond with the values returned by `+ hashKeyAttribute` and `+ rangeKeyAttribute`.

Comment: I changed them to match the ones in the AWS console and now I am getting a null value in the returned field (though the error is gone) even when I pass a ID i know is there. I feel like a idiot. The help is appreciated

Comment: Can you update the code snippet to print out the hash and range keys and post the table data row from the AWS Management Console that matches? Most likely cause is that you are sending out wrong hash and range keys.

Comment: Based on your code snippet, `UserIdString:  us-east-1:4ae0a93a-59a6-45fd-80c8-ff6b99f1d152` needs to be `Username:  us-east-1:4ae0a93a-59a6-45fd-80c8-ff6b99f1d152`. The SDK doesn't support secondary indexes, and the `rangeKey` of `- load:hashKey:rangeKey:` needs to be a table's range key.

Comment: My basic misunderstanding there. Thanks

Comment: AWS documentation is really very poor TBH! I tried to look into [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression Class Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression.html#//api/name/rangeKeyConditions) and found nothing useful. @YosukeMatsuda :(